# jQuery: execute something after an effect is finished

Tags: jquery

I have a top nav bar, when you click on an item a megamenu slides down, if you click on it again, the megamenu slides back up.

Sometimes, I have elements (links and paragraphs) whose z-index is higher than the mengamenus, so when the megamenus slide down, they appear on top of the megamenu. I solved this issue with the code below.

However, by solving this issue, another one came up and this is where I need help:

When the megamenus are sliding back up, the z-index of the elements is immediately changed back to 1, thus the elements appear on top of the megamenu while the megamenu is sliding back up.

Is there a way to have the action of changing the z-index of those elements AFTER the megamenus have finished sliding back up?

Here's my code so far:

```
$('.click-menu h6 span').click(function() {
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().next().slideUp('fast');
        $('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index', '1');
    } else {
        $('.click-menu h6 span').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.click-menu div').slideUp('fast');
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown('fast');
        $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp('fast');
        $('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index', '0');
    }
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both [`slideUp`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) and [`slideDown`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) accept optional callback parameters that execute once the animations are finished:

```
$('.click-menu h6 span').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
        $(this).removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().next().slideUp('fast', function() {
            $('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index','1');     
        });
    } else {
        $('.click-menu h6 span').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        $('.click-menu div').slideUp('fast');
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown('fast');
        $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp('fast', function() {
            $('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index','0');  
        });   
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jeff. My code hinting tells me there's a syntax error?
 $(function(){
$('.click-menu h6 span').click(function(){
if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
$(this).removeClass('selected');
$(this).parent().next().slideUp('fast', function() {
$('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index','1');
});
} else {
$('.click-menu h6 span').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');
$('.click-menu div').slideUp('fast');
$(this).parent().next().slideDown('fast');
$('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp('fast', function() {
$('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index','0');  
});   
});

Comment: The error appears in the last }); --
Sorry, posting code on the comments section is the worse.

Comment: There we go! I misread your initial code, overlooking the original indentation (and the end of the else clause) when I copied it.

Comment: Jeff, your code was exactly what I needed, I did a couple of adjustments to it and it worked perfectly, see my answer and code below. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

[`.slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) takes a callback...you can run the `z-index` changes in a function there, like this:

```
$(this).parent().next().slideUp('fast', function() {
  $('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index','1'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the setTimeout() function then check for a certain class.  If the class exists you can use an addClass or toggleClass function to add a new z-index.

Answer (score 0):

Working code based on Jeff's code and Nick Craver's suggestion:

```
$(function(){
//Megamenus     
$('.click-menu h6 span').click(function(){
    if ($(this).hasClass('selected')) {
    $(this).removeClass('selected');
    $(this).parent().next().slideUp('', function() {
        $('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index','1');
});

} else {
    $('.click-menu h6 span').removeClass('selected');       
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    $('.click-menu div').slideUp('fast');
    $(this).parent().next().slideDown('fast');
    $('.generic-box a, .generic-box p').css('z-index','0');
    $('.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs').slideUp('');
    }
  });
});
```

I had to remove the z-index:0 out of the function since '.radio-btns-wrapper-wjs' wasn't the object injecting the z-index:0.

Thanks again :)